# turn off a pangesturderecognizer with a double tapgesturerecognizer and a swift flow

Tags: ios, swift, class, uigesturerecognizer

I have a button on my main UI that I can create views programmatically with. That is down at the bottom. They come out as a green circle that I can move around using a PanGestureRecognizer.

My goal is to turn off the PanGestureRecognizer with a TapGestureRecognizer (I would like it to be a double tap) essentially locking that specific view in place once I double tap it.

This is the code that I have so far. When I tap the view it does in fact change color, but I cannot figure out how to reference the PanGestureRecognizer to disable it.

```
class MakeACircle: UIView {
var circleCenter = CGPoint()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    var checkSomething = 1



    init() {

        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        UITapGestureRecognizer().numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func dragCircle(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let target = gesture.view!

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began, .ended:
            circleCenter = target.center
        case .changed:
            let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.superview)
            target.center = CGPoint(x: circleCenter.x + translation.x, y: circleCenter.y + translation.y)
        default: break
        }
    }

    func freeze(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

            switch checkSomething {
            case 1:
                self.panGesture.isEnabled = false
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                checkSomething += 1
                print(checkSomething)


            case 2:
                self.panGesture.isEnabled = true
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                checkSomething -= 1
                print(checkSomething)

            default:
                break
            }

        }
}
```

I am creating the view programmatically with this IBButton

```
@IBAction func makeACircle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let something = MakeACircle()
    self.view.addSubview(something)

    something.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: something, action: #selector(something.dragCircle(gesture:))))
    something.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: something, action: #selector(something.freeze(gesture:))))

    something.center = self.view.center

}
```

The taps work, as you can see I have a switch in there to turn it colors.. it prints the number and turns color.. but it happens with just one tap and the pan stays on.

Any insight is greatly appreciated! This is my first execution of this, I know I'm right at the door, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I am not sure I understood but did look at `cancelsTouchesInView`. If you look at the documentations `When this property is true (the default) and the receiver recognizes its gesture, the touches of that gesture that are pending are not delivered to the view and previously delivered touches are cancelled through a touchesCancelled(_:with:) message sent to the view. If a gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if the value of this property is false, the view receives all touches in the multi-touch sequence.`

Comment: I changed up my explanation just a bit, maybe that will help. I don't want to cancel touches, because I would like to be able to disable and enable the pan gesture through a touch gesture. So, if I double tap a view then it is locked in place. If I double tap it again, then I can move it again. Does the make a little more sense?

I can't figure out how to reference the specific PanGestureRecognizer on my instances to get them to disable through the code in my class - I think that is where I'm going wrong.

thanks for your help

Comment: Just a ruff idea...   func freeze(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

            switch tap{
            case 1: if tap != true {
                self.panGesture.isEnabled = false
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
         
}

            case 2:  if tap == true {
                self.panGesture.isEnabled = true
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
             }

            default:
                break
            }

        } // try this see what happens....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not storing a reference to self.panGesture on your MakeACircle() object when you add it, so when you try to disable it, it doesn't do anything. Where is self.panGesture being set?

instead of this:

```
something.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: something, action: #selector(something.dragCircle(gesture:))))
```

try this:

```
something.panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: something, action: #selector(something.dragCircle(gesture:)))
something.addGestureRecognizer(something.panGesture)
```

**UPDATE**

for your tap gesture recognizer, make sure you're also storing a reference to it in the same way you are with the panGesture.

in your init(), you have:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer().numberOfTapsRequired = 2
```

but that won't do anything because it's not the same tap gesture you added when you said

```
something.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(...))
```

So you should do something like you did with the other gesture

```
something.tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: something, action: #selector(whatever))
something.tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
something.addGestureRecognizer(something.tap)
```

Comment: I love you. This worked! It also gives me a little bit more insight on how to make these things work inside of classes.. so I am very grateful!

Comment: @TomMohr I'm glad it worked out for you! The questions "where is it being set?" and "where is it defined?" will lead you in the right direction for lots of confusing bugs like this :)

Comment: ok - can I ask you a follow up question? I'm trying to get it so the tap recognizer initiates after two taps... it's doing it after 1. I have tried EVERYWHERE to get it to read and nothing seems to work. I again feel like it's right on the tip of my fingers... :(    -- I appreciate it if you can help once more.

Comment: I got it to work once... and now for the life of me can't figure it out!

Comment: ok never mind - I got it... I had to add it to the IBButton and then it worked. It's not ideal as I'd like... but it gets the job done. I'll have to continue to think about the difference between being set and being defined as you say. Not quite sure I know the difference yet :)

Comment: @TomMohr I think you were having a similar problem as before with trying to set numerOfTapsRequired on a tapGestureRecognizer that you don't have a reference to. Check my updated answer

Comment: I did that and it actually works now - any ideas on how I can put that in to the init() of the class so that I am not having to put it in the IBButton?

Comment: it looks like you didn't quite finish your update... the last thing you said was "and in your init()"

Comment: woops, that last line was a mistake. 

But you should be able to move all of the gesture recognizer code from the button action to init(). You'd just need to change it from "something" to "self". So like self.tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(..) and so on. Then, whenever you create an instance of the view, it will add it automatically